# how to safely (basic) auth to private PyPI with zc.buildout

Tags: python, buildout

I've been so far using lovely.buildouthttp for a long time, to authenticate buildout to my private PyPI server.

The key required functionality is its ability to use credentials from a separate file. I do not want to enter credentials in the buildout config file itself.

Does zc.buildout nowadays have the ability to use basic auth credentials from another file as well? I could not find this information.

I know there's also isotoma.basicauth.buildout (have not tried it out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buildout can use data from `.pypirc`

```
[repo_name]
repository:https://your.egg.repo
username:the_userid
password:the_password
realm:your_basicauth_realm
```

With that, e.g. the following kind of entry in buildout will authenticate correctly, without having to include the credentials in the url:

```
[buildout]
find-links =
   http://your.egg.repo/packages
```

Comment: Care to add a note on the required buildout.cfg entry as well?

Comment: what is this "required buildout.cfg entry" ?

Comment: @sunew see the addition to the answer

Comment: Is that still a thing? I can't make it work: zc.buildout == 2.9.5 :(

Comment: Soved, thanks: https://community.plone.org/t/zc-buildout-private-pypi-server-resources-basic-auth-support-in-find-links/10893/2?u=sneridagh and sorry for the noise.

Comment: IOW, it is still a thing.